# from windows phone to windows 8

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, windows-8

I wrote the below code for Windows Phone 7.5. Do you know how these should been written for Windows 8?

```
Me.NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri(String.Format("/ImagePage.xaml?tag={0}", li.Tag), UriKind.Relative))

Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As NavigationEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnNavigatedTo(e)
    If Me.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("tag") Then
        Me.tagname = Me.NavigationContext.QueryString("tag")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please tell us what your problem with this code is if you try to run it on windows 8.

Comment: @evotopid: I think the OP really means Windows 8.

Comment: Yes I seen that and so I edited it... :)

Comment: i am talking about metro apps
these items have been changed ... 
win RT is really diferent from silverlight ;)

Comment: Have you tried to compile this against WinRT?

Answer (score 2):

In Win8 WinRT you navigate by specifying the type

`rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ImagePage), li.Tag)`

not by specifying the XAML URI/location

`NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/ImagePage.xaml?tag={0}", li.Tag)))`

(if you are using a `Frame` control which is the default case)

Comment: you can also pass additional parameter in Navigate call:                 frame.Navigate(typeof(ImagePage), tag); Use NavigationEventArgs property Parameter to get value provided in Navigate call.